# Operator with Ternary Return and Short-Circuit

Tags: c++, boolean, short-circuiting, ternary

I want an operator capable of short-circuiting an evaluation on `true` **or** `false` but also having a return that indicates continued testing is needed.

---

For example, lexicographic string comparison between two strings `first` and `second`:

- if `first[0] < second[0]`, we can end the comparison by returning `true`
- otherwise, if `first[0] > second[0]`, we can end the comparison by returning `false`
- otherwise, `first[0] == second[0]` holds, and we need to continue with the second character of both strings.

The trivial solution requires two comparisons:

```
bool firstIsEarlier(std::string first, std::string second){
    if(first[0] < second[0]){
        return true;
    }else if(first[0] > second[0]){
        return false;
    }
    // first[0] == second[0] holds
    // continue with second character..
}
```

My hack solution has been to use `if`-`else if` blocks and an `int` which will give me a positive number for `true` or a negative number for `false`, a `0` indicates continue testing.

```
bool firstIsEarlier(std::string first, std::string second){
    if(int i = first[0] - second[0]){
        return i < 0;
    }
    else if(i = first[1] - second[1]){
        return i < 0;
    }
    else if(i = first[2] - second[2]){
        return i < 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So as you can see the only way for me to force the short-circuit is to list each condition in an `else if`. A good solution would be a way for me to do this all on one line and preserve the short circuit. A great solution would be if there was an `operator#` to do something like this:

```
bool firstIsEarlier(std::string first, std::string second){
    return first[0] # second[0] ## first[1] # second[1] ## first[2] < second[2];
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, how do you report "needs continued testing" in the above example?

Comment: `true`, `false` and `0` ? Question is vague!

Comment: @MarcoA. if `first[0]` is the same character as `second[0]` I need to go test the next character. In the `if`-`else if` blocks I'm using the fact that if the characters are the same the result of their subtraction will be 0.

Comment: How about using a variadic template and lambdas? Or are you more into comparing to strings the hard way here? BTW: Are you sure there is a difference in a valid index for both?

Comment: @Deduplicator I was thinking about that but I don't understand the question :|

Comment: @Ajay Not `true`, `false`, and 0, `true`, `false`, and continue testing. I want a better paradigm for doing this. Perhaps the question is vague because I can only describe the paradigm I'm looking for by what it does. If there's something I can clarify let me know.

Comment: @Deduplicator The `std::string` comparison was just a simple example to convey what I want, I understand that it's unsafe and bad. I don't know much of anything about varadic templates, and I don't know how to use lambdas to accomplish this. If you have a solution please share!

Comment: "A good solution would be a way for me to do this all on one line and preserve the short circuit." You can use ternary operator. That doesnt necessarily mean it wont generate the same code the function above would.

Comment: @TheOne I hear so much griping about how bad nesting ternaries is that I'd completely blocked it out of my mind. It would accomplish getting this into a single line. Hopefully someone has a better solution though...

Comment: one line != simple/short instructions. Control flow in here is innevitable. And no you can not create your own operators, and # is not something you can overload. Also dont take strings by value, pass them by reference(`bool firstIsEarlier(std::string& first, std::string& second)`). Also since you dont change contents of the string, you could make it const

Comment: @TheOne It should also be said that I should check the `std::string` length before comparison, but I just wanted a very simple example. As far as control flow, I thought that `||` and `&&` operators didn't compile into `else_if`s. Is that wrong?

Comment: From the downvotes, I concluded that the question might not (have been) clear enough. I've tried to clarify it based on your comments. Please roll it back / re-edit it if you think it doesn't help.

Comment: This can be done either via expression templates or via comparisons with side-effects à la `bool result; bool undecided = compare(first[0], second[0], result) || compare(first[1], second[1], result) || ... ; if(!undecided) return result;` -- neither of which I find elegant.

Comment: @dyp Thanks for the edits, sometimes I'm too deep in the weeds to see why people can't find me. Your edits make it much clearer. Is `compare` in your comments the one from `std::string`, or a function I should write? Also I'm not sure what an "expression template" is.

Comment: `compare` is something you would have to write; e.g. `bool compare(char l, char r, bool& result) { result = l < r; return l != r; }` -- *expression templates* is a very powerful but complicated way to store expressions in a data structure, the expressions can then be evaluated according to some algorithm (which allows e.g. lazy evaluation). See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)

Comment: Uh, there's been a flaw in my logic: `compare` returns `false` if it's undecided, so the boolean variable should be named `decided`: `bool decided = compare(first[0], second[0], result) || ... ; if(decided) return result;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably *should* achieve this with

```
bool firstIsEarlier(std::string first, std::string second) {
    return first < second;
}
```

or more generally with `std::lexicographical_compare`.

You can do *exactly* what you ask with expression templates though, and I'll show you how.

There are a few limitations though:

1. you can't create new operators, so you have to choose *two* operators you want to overload: one for the leaf comparisons, and one for the short-circuit combination.

   (You could use a single operator if you really wanted, but it'd be (even more) confusing and would require lots of parentheses)
2. you can't really do this when both operands are primitives. If you could, your code would look like:

   ```
   bool firstIsEarlier(std::string first, std::string second){
       return first[0]^second[0] <<= first[1]^second[1] <<= first[2]^second[2];
   }
   ```

   but actually you'd need to wrap your `char`s in some value container for it to work.

---

First, we need a simple tri-state type. We can just enumerate it:

```
enum class TriState {
    True = -1,
    Maybe = 0,
    False = 1
};
```

Next, we need some *thing* to represent our `first[0]^second[0]` leaf expression, which evaluates to our tri-state type:

```
template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
struct TriStateExpr {
    LHS const &lhs_;
    RHS const &rhs_;

    TriStateExpr(LHS const &lhs, RHS const &rhs) : lhs_(lhs), rhs_(rhs) {}

    operator bool () const { return lhs_ < rhs_; }    
    operator TriState () const {
        return (lhs_ < rhs_ ? TriState::True :
                (rhs_ < lhs_ ? TriState::False : TriState::Maybe)
               );
    }
};
```

Note that we're just requiring a working `operator<` for our types - we could generalize this to use an explicit comparator if necessary.

Now, we need the non-leaf part of the expression tree. I'm forcing it to a right-to-left expression tree, so the left-hand expression is always a leaf, and the right-hand expression can be a leaf or a complete sub-tree.

```
template <typename LLHS, typename LRHS, typename RHS>
struct TriStateShortCircuitExpr {
    TriStateExpr<LLHS, LRHS> const &lhs_;
    RHS const &rhs_;

    TriStateShortCircuitExpr(TriStateExpr<LLHS, LRHS> const &lhs, RHS const &rhs)
        : lhs_(lhs), rhs_(rhs)
    {}

    operator TriState () const {
        TriState ts(lhs_);
        switch (ts) {
        case TriState::True:
        case TriState::False:
            return ts;
        case TriState::Maybe:
            return TriState(rhs_);
        }
    }

    operator bool () const {
        switch (TriState(lhs_)) {
        case TriState::True:
            return true;
        case TriState::False:
            return false;
        case TriState::Maybe:
            return bool(rhs_);
        }
    }
};
```

Now, you want some syntactic sugar, so we have to choose which operators to overload. I'll use `^` for the leaves (on the grounds that it's like `<` rotated 90 degrees clockwise):

```
template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
TriStateExpr<LHS, RHS> operator^ (LHS const &l, RHS const &r) {
    return TriStateExpr<LHS, RHS>(l,r);
}
```

and `<<=` for the non-leaves:

```
template <typename LLHS, typename LRHS, typename RLHS, typename RRHS>
TriStateShortCircuitExpr<LLHS, LRHS, TriStateExpr<RLHS, RRHS>>
    operator<<= (TriStateExpr<LLHS, LRHS> const &l,
                 TriStateExpr<RLHS, RRHS> const &r) {
    return TriStateShortCircuitExpr<LLHS, LRHS, TriStateExpr<RLHS, RRHS>>(l, r);
}

template <typename LLHS, typename LRHS, typename... RARGS>
TriStateShortCircuitExpr<LLHS, LRHS, TriStateShortCircuitExpr<RARGS...>>
    operator<<= (TriStateExpr<LLHS, LRHS> const &l,
                 TriStateShortCircuitExpr<RARGS...> const &r) {
    return TriStateShortCircuitExpr<LLHS, LRHS,
                                    TriStateShortCircuitExpr<RARGS...>>(l, r);
}
```

The main considerations are that the leaf operator should ideally have higher precedence, and the non-leaf operator should associate right-to-left. If you used a left-to-right associative operator instead, `TriStateShortCircuitExpr::operator` would recurse down the left-hand-side subtree, which seems inelegant for this application.

Comment: WOW! I really want to benefit from understanding your hard work here. I'm trying to wrap my head around this. Do I understand correctly that even if the first argument is `TRUE` or `FALSE` all the `TriStateShortCircuitExpr`s must be constructed? For example this should create 2 `TriStateShortCircuitExpr`s but only evaluate the first one's `lhs_` when cast to `bool`: FAL ^ SE <<= MAY ^ BE <<= MAY ^ BE

Comment: Yup, the entire expression tree is constructed, and only evaluation is short-circuited. Hopefully evaluation is either expensive compared to construction, or involved some side-effect we can now avoid.